# Difficulty with rotation in opengl 3

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have a problem with my code. I am rendering two objects at the moment. They are floor and figure. Floor is in VAO[0] and figure in VAO[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Drm.jpg). My problem is that I can not see the object floor. I know I have to change the view of the object floor to make it visible. I want to do this with an rotation. I only want to change floor. Here is my hole code. Could someone please help me. I only want to use modern opengl in this content opengl 3.3. I want to have my view like this: [My scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Drm.jpg) The red area is floor and the green is figure.
How can I achieve my objective. For your information. This is a test scene. My distant objective is hole scene like in a 3d game. So this means more polygones for the floor and rest of the scence like walls, ceillings, objects in the room and nps. All made with sprites, as I think this would be the best way if will not use a 3d programm to create 3d models. So if you have tips for my objects, appreciate it.
Thank you for your help.

```
#define GLFW_NO_GLU
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

int main()
{
    if(glfwInit()==GL_FALSE)
    {
        std::cerr<<"GLFW FAIL";
        return 1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT,GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 748, "My Game", NULL, NULL);
    if (window==GL_FALSE)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Open Window FAIL";
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = true;

    if(glewInit()!=GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cerr<<"GLEW FAIL";
        return 1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 748);

    const GLchar* vertexshadersrc="#version 330 core\n"
                            "layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
                            "uniform mat4 matrix;\n"
                            "void main()\n"
                            "{\n"
                            "gl_Position = gl_Position=matrix * position;\n"
                            "}\0";
    const GLchar* fragmentshadersrc="#version 330 core\n"
                              "out vec4 color;\n"
                              "void main()\n"
                              "{\n"
                              "color=vec4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);\n"
                              "}\0";

    GLuint vertexshader=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexshader,1,&vertexshadersrc,NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexshader);

    GLint compile_ok;
    GLint errlength;
    GLchar* errmsg;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexshader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok);
    if(compile_ok==GL_FALSE)
    {
      glGetShaderiv(vertexshader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&errlength);
      errmsg=new GLchar[errlength];
      glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexshader,errlength,&errlength,errmsg);
      std::cerr<<"Vertexshader";
      std::cerr<<errmsg;
      return 1;
    }


    GLuint fragmentshader=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentshader,1,&fragmentshadersrc,NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentshader);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentshader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_ok);
    if(compile_ok==GL_FALSE)
    {
      glGetShaderiv(fragmentshader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&errlength);
      errmsg=new GLchar[errlength];
      glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentshader,errlength,&errlength,errmsg);
      std::cerr<<"Fragmentshader";
      std::cerr<<errmsg;
      return 1;
    }

    GLuint programm=glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programm,vertexshader);
    glAttachShader(programm,fragmentshader);
    glLinkProgram(programm);
    glDeleteShader(vertexshader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentshader);

    GLfloat floor[]=
    {
        -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   
        -1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    };

    GLfloat floorc[]=
    {

    1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f
    };

    GLfloat figure[] = {
        -0.2f, 0.4f, -0.1f,
        -0.2f, 0.0f, -0.1f,
        0.2f, 0.4f, -0.1f,
        0.2f, 0.0f, -0.1f 
    };

    GLfloat figurec[]=
    {
        0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f
    };

    GLfloat tree[] = {
        -0.7f, 0.4f, -0.1f,
        -0.7f, 0.0f, -0.1f,
        -0.3f, 0.4f, -0.1f,
        -0.3f, 0.0f, -0.1f
    };

    GLuint VAO[3], VBO[6];
    glGenVertexArrays(3, VAO);
    glGenBuffers(6, VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(floor),floor,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(floorc),floorc,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO[1]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(figure), figure, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[3]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(figurec), figurec, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO[2]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[4]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tree), tree, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);

    glm::mat4 projection;
    projection=glm::perspective(45.0f,4.0f/3.0f,0.1f,100.0f);
    glm::mat4 modelview;
    modelview=glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f),glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
    glm::mat4 mpmatrix=projection*modelview;

    //GLuint position=glGetAttribLocation(programm,"position");
    GLuint matrixuni=glGetUniformLocation(programm,"matrix");
    //glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(GLvoid*)0);
    glUseProgram(programm);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixuni,1,GL_FALSE,&mpmatrix[0][0]);


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO[1]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        /*glBindVertexArray(VAO[2]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);*/

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I know I have to translate the object floor to make it visible. I want to do this with an rotation" Do you want to tranlsate it, or rotate it (or maybe even both)?

Answer (score 0):

Image on the screen generated from 3 matrices: projection matrix, view matrix and model matrix. Seems that you forget about view matrix. I replaced your matrix part by this code:

```
glm::mat4 projection;
projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

glm::mat4 view;
view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0, 0.25, 0.75), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));

glm::mat4 modelview;
modelview = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));

glm::mat4 mpmatrix = projection*view*modelview;
```

And I got this picture:
[image]

It's look like [your picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Drm.jpg) but both objects have red color because they use same shaders where color sets as red.

**UPD:**
Maybe for you will be enough decrease a little floor height:

```
    GLfloat floor[] = {
    -1.0f, -0.05f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, -0.05f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -0.05f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -0.05f, -1.0f,
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so fare. But the object figure is not 100% vertical as you rotate with lookat all objects. I only want to change the object floor and don't want to have an effect on the other objects, because they should all be parallel to the screen, which means 100% vertical. If you have an idea than please post it.

Comment: You can set same height for two points in `lookAt` function. `view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0, 0.1, -1.75), glm::vec3(0, 0.1, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));`. Is it help to you? In this case you will be have XY plane with z=0. And you can watch to this plane (from point with z<0) such as your screen.

Comment: @Crane please accept my answer if this helped in your current problem.